# save documents files in a plist file

Tags: ios, plist

I have an app for iOS that uses Filesharing,i want to save the files of documents in a 'BOOK.plist',only save the filetype is .txt  's files.how an I save these files and display in a tableview?

Hope for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store your txt files in a plist. You can save your documents in the documents directory of your application sandbox. You can get the path to the doc directory via this code:

```
NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentFolderPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex: 0];
```

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1233731

The code examples used will be helpful when you want to display the directory in the tableView. Hope i could help.

Comment: Your welcome, if that helped, you should check the checkmark on the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
self.frlistName2 = [[manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectoryPath error:nil]pathsMatchingExtensions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"txt"]];

NSString *obj = @".txt";
frlisturls2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
NSString *temp;
NSMutableString *mp3Path = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int j =0;
for(int i =0 ; i< [frlistName2 count]; i++)
{
    mp3Path  = [NSMutableString stringWithString:documentsDirectoryPath];
    [mp3Path appendString:@"/"];

    temp = [frlistName2 objectAtIndex:i];
    if([temp hasSuffix :obj])
    {
        [mp3Path appendString: temp];
        [frlisturls2 addObject: mp3Path];
        j++;
    }
            [mp3Path release];

    NSLog(@"frlisturls2 is%@:",frlisturls2);
}
```

Above code display the files from iTunes file-sharing,and save these files' url in a array